# Data loading to qsqlquery from database

Tags: database, postgresql, qt

I want to load 1000000 record to qt with qsqlquery.
In my table there are 20 field. When I select query in database fetch time is 2 sec but when I use qsqlquery fetch time is 47 sec.
Why this is happening and how can do this in optimize way?

```
QSqlquery query(db);
query.exec("select * from my_table limit 1000000");
```

My database is postgres.

Comment: is the exec call taking that long? try measuring and printing the actual time it is taking using `QTime time; time.start(); /* your query.exec()*/ qDebug("%d msecs", time.elapsed())` in order to identify the bottleneck. maybe updating your model and views is taking the long time.

Comment: I used QElapsedtimer and start it before exec and elapsed it after exec and show this time.

Comment: What do you mean "When I select query in database fetch time is 2 sec"? How do you make this query? Maybe not all results fetched at once?

Comment: In postgres I wrote in SQL language and get result. In 2 sec get all data. in postgres if you run your SQL code with ctrl+F7 ,the code just run and not show data in table and you can see just fetch time.